# SIM800 Sim application toolkit on rpi

Tags: sim-toolkit

I m trying to access sim toolkit SIM800 with modem on RPI . When i tried to access AT +STKMENU=00, it is throwing operation not allowed error , Can some one suggests me how to access sim toolkit from RPI/linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DID u try this first "AT+STKMENU=?" And "AT+STKMENU?" 
i also tried but some fails due to not ON STKPCI. please try first steps & tell. Thanx